# Setting type date in R with format '05-Mar-2020 17:00:00'

Tags: r, datetime

I have a large amount of data with 18000 rows. One of the columns is a combined date and time. In the csv file the format is "05/03/2020  05:00:00 PM". When i read the csv into R it turns into a character with the format "05-Mar-2020 17:00:00". I need R to understand this column as the date and time.

I have tried the following and it just replaces the DateTimes with NAs.
'dat' is the dataframe and 'DateTime' is the column name.

```
dat[['DateTime']] <- as.POSIXct(dat[['DateTime']], format = "%d%-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide us with an example of how `dat` looks like.

Comment: Do you think there is a chance that the dates are being parsed correctly, but R chooses to display said dates in its own way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- "05-Mar-2020 17:00:00"

as.POSIXct(x, format = "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")

# [1] "2020-03-05 17:00:00 CET"
```

use `help(strptime)` to see all format codes, you see that %b is used for the abbreviated month name instead of %m and that you had a redundant % sign as well.

Or you can use the lubridate package and do:

```
lubridate::dmy_hms(x)
```

Comment: But your input data has (bad !!) twelve hour format which need a different input format, `%I` instead of `%H` if memory serves.  Stick with ISO8601 date input if you can.

Comment: OP mentions the csv itself has the 12h format but mentions that she ends up with the `%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S` i.e. `"05-Mar-2020 17:00:00"` with a 24h format in R. I took that as a starting point. Being aware of `%I` versus `%H` is surely a good addition though. And it is always a good idea to consult `help(strptime)` to verify your exact user case.